# Race condition in rejection after remigration

Tags: bug, migration, migration-rejection

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633119/find-all-the-special-graphs-which-can-reduced-to-the-shortest-paths-graph) was originally posted to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). It was then [migrated](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/find-all-the-special-graphs-which-can-reduced-to-the-shortest-paths-graph) to [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), where it is off-topic. On 2012-06-27, the question was closed on Computational Science and remigrated to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) instead (where it is on-topic, and it remained open).

However the migration is marked as rejected on Stack Overflow. The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8633119/revisions) shows that:

- 12:36 Bill undeletes the migration stub, reopens the question, and migrates it to CS.
- 16:47 The migration is rejected, even though nothing happened on CS.

I presume that the rejection at 16:47 is when the question was deleted from its first target site, Scicomp. This seems to have rewritten the history of the question to mark the May 28 closing as plain “off-topic”, while rejecting the latest migration.

Please ensure that rejecting a prior migration has no effect on the current migration.

Comment: I've seen this happen with a Mathematica question before, too. At least it sounds similar.